# Sql Search in millions of records. Possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table in my `sql server 2005` database which contains about 50 million records.
I have `firstName` and `LastName` columns, and I would like to be able to allow the user to search on these columns without it taking forever. 
Out of indexing these columns, is there a way to make my query work fast?
Also, I want to search similar sounded names. for example, if the user searches for Danny, I would like to return records with the name Dan, Daniel as well. It would be nice to show the user a rank in % how close the result he got to what he actually searched.
I know this is a tuff task, but I bet I'm not the first one in the world that face this issue :)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: About "rank in % how close the result": you need to work out some algorithm for calculation of this percent.

Comment: You could use [DIFFERENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258844(v=SQL.80).aspx) to calculate the "rank in % how close"

Comment: "Out of indexing these columns" - Why don't you want to index these columns?

Comment: A regular index is not useful when you use LIKE in your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried full text indexing?  I used it on free text fields in a table over 1 million records, and found it to be pretty fast.  Plus you can add synonyms to it, so that Dan, Danial, and Danny all index as the same (where you get the dictionary of name equivalents is a different story).  It does allow wildcard searches as well.  Full text indexing can also do rank, though I found it to be less useful on names (better for documents).

Comment: Full text indexing would only give answers if the text is strictly the same. It is fast, indeed, but not what the author wanted.

Answer (score 3):

We have databases with half a billion of records (Oracle, but should have similar performances). You can search in it within a few milli seconds if you have proper indexes. In your case, place an index on firstname and lastname. Using binary-tree index will perform good and will scale with the size of your database. Careful, LIKE clauses often break the use of the index and degrades largely the performances. I know MySQL can keep using indexes with LIKE clauses when wildcards are only at the right of the string. You would have to make similar search for SQL Server.

String similarity is indeed not simple. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_similarity_measures, you'll see some of the possible algorithms. Cannot say if SQL Server do implement one of them, dont know this database. Try to Google "SQL Server" + the name of the algorithms to maybe find what you need. Otherwise, you have code provided on Wiki for various languages (maybe not SQL but you should be able to adapt them for a stored procedure).

Answer (score 0):

use FUll TEXT SEARCH enable for this table and those columns, that will create full text index for those columns.